# Wrong price for configurable product in cart using SCP and ajax

Tags: ajax, magento-1.7

I have a problem with the product list page (add to cart- fancy box) when you hover over product a button appears so you can quickly add a product to the cart once you do this a pop up (fancy box) appears - example of theme im using  http://hellothemes.com/demo/?framework=hellonevada

all is well until you choose an option and the price resets to zero 
once you select the option and add to cart the lowest priced option appears only.

I am using simple configurable products and using excellence Ajax extension which I believe are the issue i belive it could be the javascript

I also notice that when the page loads the add to cart button says quick view then within a second or two changes to add to cart as if its loading one page the reverting back to another

Would really appreciate a bit of guidance on this on

Comment: i managed to fix this thanks to someone from github for anyone who has the same problem i had to add this code on line 60 in my ajax.xml file -  app/design/frontend/default/THEME/layout/ajax.xml  - <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/scp_product_extension.js</name></action>

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this thanks to someone from github.

For anyone who has the same problem I had to add this code on line 60 in my ajax.xml file `app/design/frontend/default/THEME/layout/ajax.xml`

```
<action method="addItem">
   <type>skin_js</type>
   <name>js/scp_product_extension.js</name>
</a‌​ction>
```